# How to use std::default_delete(const default_delete<U>&);?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, memory-management, constructor

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete

1)

```
constexpr default_delete() = default;
```

2)

```
template<class U>
default_delete(const default_delete<U>& d);
```

1) Constructs a std::default_delete object.

2) Constructs a std::default_delete object from another std::default_delete object. This constructor will only participate in overload resolution if U* is implicitly convertible to T*.

**Is there any example to illustrate the form 2) is useful under some cases?**

Comment: I guess it is required to be able to assign a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.